# Call string into a string class

Tags: java, android, xml

I use `random` for show differents setenses in my app.
I have two `XML Ress` file with somes sentenses, but i can't use `random` for chose the `XML Ress`.

**That work like this :**

`[Choose a nickname from 4 edittext] + [Choose a XML Ress] + [Choose a nickname from 4 edittext]`.

This code take random nickname, that's work. But the problem is for the `XML Ress`...

**EDIT** : The second problem is `caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array at com.XX.onCreate(phrasesgenerator_players.java:65)`. The line is `choosegame[rgenerator.nextInt(choosegame.length)]`
**Activity (edited):**

```
public class phrasesgenerator_players extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final Random rgenerator = new Random();
    private TextView tv;
    String[] playerge;
    private String[] myString;
    private String[] myString2;
    private String[] choosegame = (String[]) ArrayUtils.addAll(myString, myString2);


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Window window = getWindow();
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor("#2980b9"));
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_phrasesgenerator);

        View view = this.getWindow().getDecorView();
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#3498db"));

        playerge= new String[] {"player1", "player2", "player3", "player4"};

        Resources res = getResources();

        Random random = new Random();

        myString = res.getStringArray(R.array.phrases_avecjoueurs);
        myString2 = res.getStringArray(R.array.phrases_avecjoueurs_defis);

        String q =
                getIntent().getExtras().getString(playerge[random.nextInt(playerge.length)])
                        + " "
                        + choosegame[rgenerator.nextInt(choosegame.length)]
                        + " "
                        + getIntent().getExtras().getString(playerge[random.nextInt(playerge.length)]);

        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        tv.setText(q);
    }
}
```

**I have try to use :**

```
choosegame = new String[]{myString, myString2};
```

But i have : Incompatibles types. Found: 'java.lang.string[]', required 'java.lang.string'.

I have try to use too

```
getString(choosegame[rgenerator.nextInt(choosegame.length)])
```

But i have : Cannot resolve method 'getString(java.lang.String)'

How i can use random for this 2 XML Ress.

The XML File is like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="phrases_avecjoueurs">
        <item>PH 1</item>
        <item>PH 2</item>
        <item>PH 3</item>
        <item>PH 4</item>
        <item>PH 5</item>
        <item>PH 6</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="phrases_avecjoueurs_defis">
        <item>DEFIS 1</item>
        <item>DEFIS 2</item>
        <item>DEFIS 3</item>
        <item>DEFIS 4</item>
        <item>DEFIS 5</item>
        <item>DEFIS 6</item>
    </string-array>
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code to initialize choosegame -

```
String[] choosegame = (String[])ArrayUtils.addAll(myString, myString2);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but i have a problem with ArrayUtils `Cannot resolve symbol ArrayUtils`

Comment: @Argardor Import it ... ?

Comment: May be you need to add Apache Commons. Try adding `compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.0` in your build.gradle file.

Comment: Oops, i'm tired :'( But i have a problem when i launch my Activity `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array  at com.XX.onCreate(phrasesgenerator_players.java:65)`.The line is `choosegame[rgenerator.nextInt(choosegame.length)]`

Comment: Looks like `choosegame` is null. You need to debug why it is so.

Comment: choosegame isn't null, i can call myString or myString2 in the textView i have a sentense. But choosegame didn't work. I have edited first post.

Answer (score 0):

If you want choosegame to be a new string array consisting of the strings 
myString and myString2, use

```
choosegame = {myString, myString2};
```

Comment: Thank you for you help, but that doesn't work, the problem : `Array initializer is not allow here`